# C# httplistener that parses <% c# %> code

Tags: c#, server-side, httplistener

I was wondering if it was possible to setup the HttpListener to process normal C# `<%%>` code?
So essentially I have a programming running an HttpListener right now, and all it does is replace `$varname` with whatever variable I want to output.

What I would like to do is to use a type of server side script to access all the different variables and methods in my application.

Is such a thing possible?

I looked a bit into `Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider` but I was thinking there might be a built in way that I'm not aware of.

Essentially I have an application that is a server for a client-server app, and I want to add a web gui to it so that I can call methods, and get variables and such.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure my question was straight forward. Not to mention I'm sure other people would like to know how to put Web Gui front ends into there software, so this question is also something that a lot of people could benefit from. So I'm not sure why someone downvoted it?

Comment: I cannot understand your question.  Http listener is for processing http requests and responses.  You seem to be asking how to reimplement ASP.NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may take a look at the [following article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163879.aspx). It illustrates how you could use an HttpListener to host the ASP.NET runtime and be able to process ASPX pages. It uses an [HttpListenerContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistenercontext.aspx) and an [HttpWorkerRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpworkerrequest.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it's exactly what you want to do, but if you would use IIS and ASP instead of a httplistener, `Page.ParseControl` can take a string as input, so you could parse and execute an arbitrary code block. Of course watch your input, and maybe you are forced to use a httplistener...